# code is returning data of one date only whereas i want data of every date

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
function practise()
{
    $this->load->database();
     $qry = mysql_query("select * from demmo");
  if (mysql_num_rows($qry) > 0) 
{
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
  {
      $created = $row['created'];
//from here
      $qry = mysql_query("select * from demmo where created = '$created'");

            while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
            {
                $user_id = $res['id'];
                $name = $res['name'];
                $created2 = $res['created'];
            $users[] = array('user_id' => $user_id, 'name' => $name);             
            }
                $dotts[] = array('created' => $created2);
//till here       
}                       
    return array ($dotts,$users);
}
}
```

in demmo table i am trying to fetch data and showing that data according to date .the problem is that the code is only selecting one date from the table from created rows and showing that data only .fortunately data shown is not only last but the data with actual date.

Comment: Can u share the table structure and your requirements? why are you executing the same query in nested loops?

Comment: i am little confused of what you are trying to do. the tables are both same isnt it? then the first select * will give you all the data along with date? so why the next one?

Comment: why are you trying nested query first query will give you all data of your table

Comment: also you have used same variable again for query `$qry` for both different queries

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated try to use mysqli_*

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `array` and use `array_push` to get more than one result. Right now your code is only returning the last result of the while loop:

For example, to get all of the dates:

```
$dotts = array(); 
$allusers = array(); 
while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
    {
        $user_id = $res['id'];
        $name = $res['name'];
        $created2 = $res['created'];
        array_push($dotts, $created2);
        $users[] = array('user_id' => $user_id, 'name' => $name);   
        array_push($allusers, $users);          
    }
// 
return array ($dotts,$allusers);
```

Comment: you need to return $allusers instead of $users

Comment: TY Sir! Missed that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an array and use array_push function , then only it will have more than one value.

example:

create an empty array as

```
$allUser = array();
```

then after this line

```
$users[] = array('user_id' => $user_id, 'name' => $name);
```

use array_push as

```
array_push($allUser, $users);
}
return array($dots, $allUser);
```

Comment: If you find this answer helpful, plz mark it as useful that would help other as well. @Jaspreet Singh